# Dart- getting unused variable notification even after using it

Tags: flutter, dart

What am I missing over here? I get this unused variable message even after using the variable. Here below the _userProfileImgae variable is used inside of the GestureDetector widget, but when I hover my mouse over the decalaration I get the unused variable message. Also, somebody please explain when I should be using the **this** prefix to a variable. I see some places it works without using the **this** prefix and some places not.

```
class _ProfilePictureState extends State<ProfilePicture> {
  late File _userProfileImage;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [             
          Row(
            children: [
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () async {
                  final _picker = ImagePicker();

                  PickedFile image = await _picker.pickImage(
                      source: ImageSource.gallery) as PickedFile;

                  if (image != null) {
                    setState(() {
                      this._userProfileImage = File(image.path);
                    });
                  }
                },
                child: Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/icons/plus_icon.png'),
                  width: 300,
                  height: 300,
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think your variable is considered unused because it's only written to but never read from.  As for `this`, you need to use it only to disambiguate a member variable shadowed by a local variable (or in a few special cases, such as when automatically initializing members from constructor parameters or when using redirecting constructors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get this unused variable message even after using the variable.

Although you're writing to `_userProfileImage`, you don't read it anywhere. Here's an example where the variable is being written and read:

```dart
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  File? _userProfileImage;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final File? userProfileImage = _userProfileImage;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Image(
          // =====> READING <=====
          image: userProfileImage == null 
            ? AssetImage('assets/icons/plus_icon.png') 
            : FileImage(userProfileImage),
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
        TextButton(
          child: Text("Click me"),
          onPressed: () async {
            final XFile? image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
            if (image == null) return;
            // =====> WRITING <=====
            setState(() => this._userProfileImage = File(image.path));
          },
        )
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

---

> Also, somebody please explain when I should be using the this prefix to a variable. I see some places it works without using the this prefix and some places not.

Here's another example where using `this` and not matters:

```dart
class Foo {
  final int bar = 5;
  
  void f() {
    print(bar);           // Outputs 5
    print(this.bar);      // Outputs 5
  }
  
  void g() {
    final int bar = 10;
    print(bar);           // Outputs 10
    print(this.bar);      // Outputs 5
  }
  
  void h(int bar) {
    print(bar);           // Outputs the parameter `bar`
    print(this.bar);      // Outputs 5
  }
}
```